# Cannot find Debug.startMethodTracing() trace file

Tags: android

I am having trouching using Debug.startMethodTracing() with my **Samsung Galaxy S**.

According to the Android docs, `Debug.startMethodTracing("filename")` writes to /sdcard/filename.trace, but I cannot find this file or folder in the DDMS File Explorer. The folder /sdcard is simply not there.

I've tried:

```
Debug.startMethodTracing("filename")
Debug.startMethodTracing("/mnt/sdcard/filename")
Debug.startMethodTracing("/mnt/sdcard/tmp/filename")
```

The first two attempts did not report an error but I couldn't find the files in DDMS File Explorer. The third generated a runtime exception stating I didn't have permission to write to that folder.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Barry

Comment: Follow up note: the emulator says I don't have permission to write to /sdcard/filename.trace.  WTF???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need to add [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: so how are we supposed to use tracing when targeting Android 13+ where this permission isn't granted?